# How to use session Bean in Jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

I am new for JSP, and i have one question. Please answer me.

i have bean in my project and Name of the bean called userBean, property called login as boolean.

in my jsp page my code should be like below,

```
'<% if (login == true) { %>

'<% } else { %>

'<% } %>
```

how to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

Lets say this is your bean:

```
public class UserBean implements
{
   private String firstName = null;

   public UserBean() {
   }
   public String getFirstName(){
      return firstName;
   }       
   public void setFirstName(String firstName){
      this.firstName = firstName;
   }       
}
```

You access it in the JSP File like:

```
<jsp:useBean id="UserBean" class="UserBean"> 

   <jsp:setProperty name="UserBean" property="firstName" value="Zara"/>

</jsp:useBean>
```